# how to sum time value in array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am fetching a data from my database according to client id. client id work time is different like:

00:15:00 
00:20:00
etc.

this is not an array
i make this as dynamic array

```
$time[] = $alltime;
```

result showing this:

```
  Array
(
 [0] => 00:20:00
 [1] => 00:15:00
 [2] => 00:20:00
 [3] => 00:20:00
 [4] => 00:55:00
 [5] => 00:05:00
)
```

i want to sum all time.
i tried many times and many way but output not showing according to time.
please help

Comment: Use PHP Carbon library and its API for addition and subtraction of time value.

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

Comment: convert the time into seconds, add and again convert back the seconds into time format

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get the sum, using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert the times to seconds. Note that since `strtotime` produces a timestamp relative to the Unix Epoch, you need to subtract the start of the day (`strtotime('00:00')`) from each value to get the number of seconds in the time:

```
$time = array
(
 '00:20:00',
 '00:15:00',
 '00:20:00',
 '00:20:00',
 '00:55:00',
 '00:05:00'
);
$time_in_secs = array_map(function ($v) { return strtotime($v) - strtotime('00:00'); }, $time);
$total_time = array_sum($time_in_secs);
$hours = floor($total_time / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($total_time % 3600) / 60);
$seconds = $total_time % 60;
echo "Total time is "
   . str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
   . ":" . str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) 
   . ":" . str_pad($seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Total time is 02:15:00
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CahOZ)

You could also simplify the code by using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to compute `$total_time` instead of [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$total_time = array_reduce($time, function ($c, $v) { return $c + strtotime($v) - strtotime('00:00'); }, 0);
```

[Alternate demo](https://3v4l.org/bT6lk)