# Sum of time array php - Result should be H:m:i without DAY

Tags: php

I have an array with  time values

```
 print_r($timeVal);
```

output:

```
 Array ( 
[2018-12-01] => 23:58:0 
[2018-12-02] => 23:58:0
[2018-12-03] => 23:58:0     
[2018-12-05] => 2:0:0 
)
```

so i want to calculate all those and get total time:
correct result should be

> **73:54**  and not  **3 days  1 hours 54 minutes  0 seconds**

post is not duplicate coz i viewed other posts and they show Day hour minute not just hour min

example like this :

```
 $sum = strtotime('00:00:00');
 $sum2=0;  
 foreach ($TimeVal as $v){

        $sum1=strtotime($v)-$sum;

        $sum2 = $sum2+$sum1;
    }

    $sum3=$sum+$sum2;
date("H:i:s",$sum3)  //this show 1:54:00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

Comment: did u read the post , i writed why is not duplicated, and this is SUM  not difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sum time value in array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512587/how-to-sum-time-value-in-array-in-php)

Comment: Is that *definitely* your input array? Because it has the same key twice.

Comment: @iainn  i corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to display your time in a 24-hour format, `date()` won't give you what you are looking for.

I copied your code and modified it slightly, so it does the job with the example you gave:

```
$sum = strtotime('00:00:00');
$sum1 = 0;
foreach ($TimeVal as $v){
    $sum1 += strtotime($v) - $sum;
}
$hours = $sum1 / 3600;
$minutes = ($hours - floor($hours)) * 60;

echo floor($hours) . ':' . round($minutes);
```